# How to select max marks from one subject and min marks from another subject in a student table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Select max marks from math subject and select min marks from physics subject.

I can only think of it like following:

```
Select subject, max(Marks) as Max_Marks, MIN(Marks) as Min_Marks
from Student 
group by Subject
```

But above query shows max, min for each subject.

Any other way to query this ?

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE` is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include `WHERE` clause & do conditional aggregation :

```
select max(case when Subject = 'math' then Marks end) as math_Max_Marks,
       min(case when Subject = 'physics' then Marks end) as physics_Min_Marks
from Student 
where Subject in ('math', 'physics');
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about case-when. I want to learn advance sql can you share  any resource ?

Comment: @JeetashRathi. . .  It is `case` expression Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Above three answers are correct.
This way may be easier understand

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT max(Marks) from Student WHERE subject = 'math')    AS Max_Math
, (SELECT min(Marks) from Student WHERE subject = 'physics') AS Min_Physics;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like below, with a where clause and use a case-when statement to decide whether you need to use max or min function.

```
Select subject, mark = (case when subject = 'math' then max(Marks) else min(Marks) end)
from Student 
where Subject = 'math'
   or Subject = 'physics'
group by Subject
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `WHERE` with your condition

**Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(SUBJECT varchar(12), MARK int)
INSERT INTO #temp(SUBJECT, MARK)
select 'Maths',   100  union
select 'Maths',   90  union
select 'Maths',   40  union
select 'Physics',   60  union
select 'Physics',   30  union
select 'Physics',   20  

Select subject, max(Mark) as Max_Marks, MIN(Mark) as Min_Marks
from #temp 
where Subject in ('maths','physics')
group by Subject
```

**Output:**

[image]